# How to make array inside array where common id is found multiple times in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is what my Array looks like:

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question] => Which career is help to achive mca?
            [answer_id] => 1
            [answer] => nmit bangalore is the best college ever for mca
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question] => Which career is help to achive mca?
            [answer_id] => 6
            [answer] => rnsit is the best college
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question] => Which career is help to achive mca?
            [answer_id] => 7
            [answer] => city college is best for mca
        )
```

If you see the first three sets, `question_id` and `question` are the same, while `answer_id` and `answer` are different for the three sets. I need all three answers inside an array without `question_id` and `question`, like one question with multiple answers. I'm trying to achive this in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `foreach` loop to incrementally construct an associative array comprising of questions and the associative answers, like this:

```
// Declare $result_arr array to store the result array
$result_arr = array();

// Suppose $arr is your original array
foreach($arr as $obj){
    $result_arr[$obj->question_id]['question_id'] = $obj->question_id;
    $result_arr[$obj->question_id]['question'] = $obj->question;
    $result_arr[$obj->question_id]['answers'][] = array('answer_id' => $obj->answer_id, 'answer' => $obj->answer);
}
$result_arr = array_values($result_arr);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result_arr);
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/589328).

Comment: @pavankumar.p You're very welcome! :-) Consider accepting the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)